# How to fix 'keras' has no attribute 'datasets'

Tags: python, keras

I was following a keras tutorial and I had run this piece of code

```
import keras
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

and I get this error message

> AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'datasets'

I've tried to look up other people with the same question, but can't seem to find the exact answer. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using colab?

Comment: I am using Colab @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 4):

Edited code :

```
import tensorflow.keras as tk
mnist = tk.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Reference:

https://keras.io/api/datasets/

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data

Answer (score 0):

You should try as below

```
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```